# TypeError: string indices must be integers when calling pd.to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I created the following class to convert objects to a numeric type:

```
class ConvertObjectToNum:
   def convert(dataframe, column):
       dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce'))
```

When calling the class like this

```
data_set['Qual'] = ConvertObjectToNum.convert('data_set', 'Qual')
```

I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-20-4d0c321cdb16> in convert(dataframe, column)
     1 class ConvertObjectToNum:
     2     def convert(dataframe, column):
----> 3         dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce'))
     4 
     5 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, calling the to_numeric function outside of my class works just fine. So I guess it has to be a problem with how I constructed the class:

```
data_set['Qual'] = data_set['Qual'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce'))
```

Thanks for your help

E:

The values of the column are numbers in a String format. With some '-' mixed in, hence the Errors = 'coerce' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
class ConvertObjectToNum:
    @staticmethod
    def convert(dataframe, column):
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [45, 88, 56, 15, 71]})
ConvertObjectToNum.convert(df, 'Weight')
print (df.dtypes) #  Weight    int64
```

I made the method a staticmethod.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Could you help me to understand what I did wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how you called convert. But since the method didn't use *self*, it seemed a good bet to make it a static method (which does not rely on any internal state of the ConvertObjectToNum class). I suspect that when you called convert, you had either not instantiated the object correctly or had a mismatch on the "column" argument. (It might help to have a debug statement on your original code to see what column was. I suspect it was neither an integer nor a string.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will do the work:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
```

The class:

```
class ConvertObjectToNum:
   def convert(dataframe, column):
       dataframe[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column])
```